# Proving a Simple Inequality involving Fourier Transforms

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, fourier-transform

This is a minor technical matter that I know to be true, I just don't know how to prove it. Help would be much appreciated.

Let:$$\psi\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-2^{n}v\left|x\right|}$$ 
where $v$ is a positive constant. $\psi$ is in both $L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ and $L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, and its Fourier transform is:

$$\Psi\left(\xi\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi\left(x\right)e^{-2\pi i\xi x}dx=\frac{2}{v}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-n}}{\left(\frac{2\pi\xi}{2^{n}v}\right)^{2}+1}$$

I am trying to prove that $2\Psi\left(2\xi\right)>\Psi\left(\xi\right)$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$. Any ideas, people?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2\Psi\left(2\xi\right)=2\frac{2}{v}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-n}}{\left(\frac{2\pi(2\xi)}{2^{n}v}\right)^{2}+1} = \frac{2}{v}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-n+1}}{\left(\frac{2\pi\xi}{2^{n-1}v}\right)^{2}+1} = \frac{2}{v}\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-n}}{\left(\frac{2\pi\xi}{2^{n}v}\right)^{2}+1} >\Psi\left(\xi\right)$$
since the first term of the series is positive and sum of the rest of the terms is equal to $\Psi\left(\xi\right)$.

Comment: Wow. I did *not* see that. But I definitely *should* have. Like the ache in my neck, this is another tell-tale sign that I'm probably overworked. xD

Thanks a million!